# iOS Unit Test on AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, appdelegate

I am very new in iOS development. I want to create a function that when the app first launch, it can switch the app language base on System Language. How can I create a unit test to test that function?

Here is my code in AppDelegate.swift, I want to test "setLang" function:
Test case should be:

setLang("en", setting)

expected result: setting.string(forKey:"lang") == "en"

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    applySetting()
    return true
}

func applySetting(){
    setLang(SysLangCode: Locale.current.languageCode, UserSetting: UserDefaults.standard)
}

func setLang(SysLangCode sysLang:String?, UserSetting setting:UserDefaults){
   //Some logic to check sysLang
   setting.set(sysLang, forKey:"lang")
}
...
```

Here is my unit test, but it is failed with "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
class xxx: XCTestCase {
   var appDelegate: AppDelegate!
   func testSetLang(){
    self.appDelegate.setLang(SysLangCode: "en", UserSetting:UserDefaults.standard)
    XCTAssert(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lang") == "en")
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you added a Unit Test target to your project?

Comment: Yes, I use the default one

Comment: I have added the unit test, please have a look, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added a Unit Test target to your project then a simple Unit Test would look like:

```
func testLanguageCodeCanBeSetInUserDefaults() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Locale.current.languageCode,
                              forKey: "lang")

    XCTAssertEqual(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lang"),
                   Locale.current.languageCode)
}
```

---

To add a Unit Test target to your project:

> File > New > Target > iOS > iOS Unit Testing Bundle

---

EDIT: (Based on yours)

```
func testAppDelegateCanSetLanguageCodeToUserDefaults() {
    let appDelegate = AppDelegate()        
    appDelegate.setLang(SysLangCode: "en", 
                        UserSetting:UserDefaults.standard)

    XCTAssertEqual(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lang"),
                   "en")
}
```

Comment: But I want to test my setLang() function, it needs to input UserDefault object as a parameter, how to do this?

Comment: @VincentHo If you want to eventually test that your `AppDelegate` sets the language setting for the application properly then you need to fake the `AppDelegate`. For that, check this link: https://marcosantadev.com/fake-appdelegate-unit-testing-swift

Comment: @VincentHo But if you want to test that your `AppDelegate` has a function called `setLang(SysLangCode:UserSetting)` and calling it sets the `UserDefaults` then one dirty & quick way would be... ***Check the updated answer***

Comment: Thank you for your help!! It is very useful!